# Stream data from Google Sheets to BigQuery to visualise in Tableau

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, streaming, import.io

I am trying to create an timed, automatic data upload from Google Sheets to BigQuery so that I can visualise the data in Tableau. The data originates in import.io.

Based [on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) I have been able to use Google Apps Scripts to create a .csv from the Google Sheets file, and upload the .csv file to BigQuery as a one off. However, this cannot be used as a recurring solution because the BigQuery load script requires a static URL for the .csv file (and each .csv download file gets a unique URL).

I believe that streaming data from Google Sheets, or directly from but, having studied [Google BigQuery Analytics](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118824822.html) have not yet been able to solve this.

What steps are needed to stream data from Google Sheets to BigQuery?

Comment: Are you open to connecting import.io to BQ using Python?

Comment: I am connecting BQ to Google Spreadsheets and Google Spreadsheets to import.io using import.io's integrate script, which I copy to Google sheets. I am just taking my first steps with Python (using Mac terminal). Would be great if you could provide some links if using Python is a better way. Afraid I am an ageing analyst trying to learn some developer skills. Sorry if this is basic and I really appreciate your response.

Comment: For the import.io side, the Python client integration examples can be found here: https://import.io/data/integrate/#python

Answer (score 0):

In the example you are linking to, the URL to the csv doesn't need to be static. The example is inserting into bigquery passing the octect/stream data directly, so all you need is the reference to a csv file.

I don't know which procedure you are following to export your spreadsheet to csv, but you can take a look at this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2

You will find there how to export your csv data as a new file, then with that file you can already import from your csv (using DriveApp folder object you can get the reference to the csv file).